# How to pass global inputvalues to modules reactively?

Tags: r, shiny

I have two `modules` that takes the same from `dateRangeInput`, and therefore I want to create this `input` completely on the `UI` side, and use it globally.

However, the `output` does not change with the `input` as the MWE shows below.

**UI:**

```
library(shiny)

# Generate User Interface; ####
ui <- fluidPage(
        
        column(
                width = 2,
                h1("Controls"),
                p("This input should appear in both modules reactively."),
                dateRangeInput(
                        inputId = NS(id = NULL,"daterange"),
                        label = "Pick Date:",
                        start = Sys.Date() - 8,
                        end = Sys.Date()
                )
        ),
        
        column(
                width = 5,
                h1("Module 1"),
                p("This output should change as date range changes."),
                moduleUI("mod1")
        ),
        
        column(
                width = 5,
                h1("Module 2"),
                p("This output should change as date range changes."),
                moduleUI("mod2")
        )
        
)
```

**Server:**

```r
server <- function(input,output,server) {
        
        # Module 1
        module_1("mod1",my_input = input$daterange)
        
        # Module 2
        module_1("mod2",my_input = input$daterange)
        
        
}
```

The `modules` are created as shown below,

```r
module_1 <- function(id, my_input = NULL) {
        moduleServer(
                id, function(input, output, session) {
                        
                        
                        output$userdate <- renderText(
                                paste(my_input)
                        )
  
        }
)
}


module_2 <- function(id, my_input = NULL) {
        moduleServer(
                id, function(input, output, session) {
                        
                        
                        output$userdate <- renderText(
                                paste(my_input)
                        )
                        
                }
        )
}


moduleUI <- function(id) {
        ns <- NS(id)
        textOutput(ns("userdate"))
}
```

It accepts the initial values, but does change according to the `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- `NS(id = NULL,"daterange")` in the main app is a bit unusual, it's not wrong but in my opinion it decreases the readability, so I would just use `inputId = "daterange"`
- `input$daterange` is only reactive within the main app, so you need to wrap it into a `reactive` to pass it to the modules
- then you also have to adapt how the argument is evaluated within the modules (add brackets)

Examples with your code:

```
# Module 2
module_2("mod2",my_input = reactive({input$daterange)})
```

in the module server:

```
output$userdate <- renderText(
   paste(my_input())
)
```

I have created a tutorial for modules, maybe it helps you: https://github.com/jonas-hag/structure_your_app

Comment: Thank you for this. On an honest side note `NS(id = NULL,"daterange")` was my attempt to solve it.